# How do I create a token for a function in antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I need some help, because I know how to create a way to define a function on my language:

```
function: 
    ID ‘as’ DATATYPE ‘(‘ arguments ‘)’ instruction* EndFun;
```

My problem is, if I want to make 'void' functions, how can I prevent from user to input a 'return ID'

```
function: 
    ID (‘as’ DATATYPE)? ‘(‘ arguments ‘)’ instruction* EndFun;
```

ps: instructions token includes 'return ID'

Comment: I'm not sure you can _prevent_ wrong input since antlr is a _parser_. What you could do is check the return statements and types _after_ parsing.

Comment: To add to Thomas' comment: what you are after is a semantic requirement, not a syntactial one. So it shouldn't go into a parser rule, but in the semantic phase that is almost always necessary when parsing non-trivial languages. Bart's answer reflects this idea (in the first option).

Comment: yes you are all right, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either check after parsing if a `void` function contains a return statement (which is what I'd do), or do something like this:

```
function
 : ID 'as' DATATYPE '(' arguments ')' instruction* EndFun
 | 'void' '(' arguments ')' instruction_no_return* EndFun
 ;

instruction
 : instruction_no_return
 | 'return' ID
 ;

instruction_no_return
 : instruction_a
 | instruction_b
 | instruction_c
 ;
```

Comment: Assuming that `instruction_no_return` contains nested statements like `if '(' expression ')' instruction_no_return`, you won't be able to use `instruction_no_return` in `instruction`. You'd have to duplicate the entire thing. So I'd definitely go with option 1.